# how to convert values in a column type int to varchar in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, int

I have one table DistTable with column Dname, DID, Dcode in postgresql.

```
create table Disttable (Distname varchar, DId int, DCode varchar); 

insert into Disttable values 
   ('King',1, null), 
   ('salt lake',20, null), 
   ('Hanlulu',25, null);
```

I want to update Dcode with DId... How to write the query?

```
Update DistTable set Dcode=to_char(did)
```

.... not working

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You are duplicating data which is never a good idea in a relational database. Instead it's better to create a view that returns the number formatted the way you need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have sql query like this

update DistTable set Dcode = to_char(did, '9999');
```

You need a format mask, as Postgres has no default.

This is documented here:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

Comment: PostgreSQL does have a default for casting an integer to text. See: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE DistTable SET Dcode = did::text;
```

This does the default cast from `integer` to `text`, which is faster than the `to_char()` option.